# Why are the some backgrounds in my create-react-app site showing up differently on heroku?

Tags: heroku, create-react-app, styled-components

So, my web development business is expanding a bit and I'm finally getting around to making my own site for it. I'm using create-react-app with the associated [buildpack from mars](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) on Heroku, and the white elements show up fine when i run it on localhost, but show up as dark grey on Heroku. [Here](https://terranovus.herokuapp.com/) is a link to my site (it's clearly not complete), and [here](https://github.com/TerraNovus/TerraNovus) is a link to the github repository. Specifically, the portfolio section and the service cards are the bottom are all supposed to have white backgrounds.

The same thing with the buttons - when you hover over them they turn from red to dark grey, but locally they are white when you hover over them (and that's what they're supposed to be)

(To note, I don't actually hate it and might actually wind up incorporate that background or a slightly lighter version of it into the app itself, but I do plan on having an toggle for day mode, so I would like to know why it's doing that to correct it.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - turned out to be a dark mode extension on my chrome browser